# Show that every nonzero prime ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x^2 - y^2 - 1)$ is maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, polynomial-rings

Show that the ring $A := \mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x^2 - y^2 - 1)$ is an integral domain. Further show that every nonzero prime ideal in A is maximal.

I proved that $A$ is an integral domain by showing that $x^2 - y^2 - 1$ is an irreducible in the UFD $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$ and hence a prime. To prove that every nonzero prime ideal in $A$ is maximal I need to prove either that:

i) A is a PID, so in a sense I need to be able to express $x$ in terms of $y$ (or vice versa) but I only know that $x^2 = y^2 + 1$ in $A$.

ii)If $I$ is a prime ideal in $A$ then every non zero element in $A/I$ is invertible.

Comment: have you seen the nullstellensatz? that makes this problem much easier.

Comment: Yes I have seen the Nullstellenatz but I don't see how it can be applied since $x^2-y^2-1$ is not maximal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. Moreover this is a question from a qualifying exam, knowledge of Nullstellenatz is not assumed.

Comment: Suggestion: using your observation $x^2 = y^2+1$, if $a$ and $b$ are polys in $y$ such that the non-zero $a +x b$ belongs to the prime, one gets that the non-zero poly in $y$ $a^2 - (y^2 +1)b^2$ belongs to the prime...

Comment: So in particular if $1+x$ belongs to the prime ideal, $1-(y^2+1)=-y^2$ belongs to the prime ideal and hence $y$ belongs to the prime ideal? This tells us that prime ideals are principal but what about non prime ideals?

Comment: The suggestion was: we know that for any $B \to A$  map of rings, the inverse image of primes are primes. We know that in $B={\mathbb C}[y]$, the non-zero prime ideals are of the form $(y-\beta)$ for $\beta \in {\mathbb C}$. Hence, in the notation of your question one has a finite extension $A/I$ over ${\mathbb C}= B/(I\cap B)$, in which $x$ satisfies $x^2-\alpha^2 =0 \pmod I$, for some $\alpha \in {\mathbb C}$. Since $A/I$ is a domain, one must have that $x- \alpha =0 $ or $x +\alpha = 0$ in $A/I$. Hence, $A/I \simeq {\mathbb C}$, and is a field, hence $I$ is maximal.

Comment: I think that was probably the intended solution to the question, but the more  general fact below is v. useful to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally (than my suggestion in the comments): suppose that $A$ over $B$ is an extension such that every $a\in A$ satisfies a equation of the form
$$a^k+b_1 a^{k-1}+\cdots+ b_{k-1}a +b_k =0,\tag {*}$$
 with $b_j \in B$, ($k$ and $b_j$ depend on $a$ of course).

(Here, $B = {\mathbb C}[y]$.)

If $A$ (and so $B$) are domains, and (*) is of minimal degree for $a\not=0$, then $b_k\not =0$.

Now, if $0\not=a\in P$ ($P$ prime), we have that $b_k \in P$.  Therefore the prime $Q = B \cap P \not = 0$.

If you know that $Q$ is maximal in $B$ (as you do here!), one ends up with an extension $A/P$ over $B/Q$, where the latter is a field. To ease notation, replace $A$ with $A/P$, and $B$ with $B/Q$. The aim is to show that $A$ is a field. Using your second strategy:

Look at the  equation $(*)$.  Assume (once more) that the equation is of minimal degree for $a\not =0$. Rearranging, one has that 
$$ a ( a^{k-1} + \cdots + b_{k-1}) = - b_{k}.$$
Again, $-b_k$ is non-zero, so has a multiplicative inverse (because after relabeling, $B$ is a field). Dividing out, one gets:
$$ a \cdot (-b_k^{-1})( a^{k-1} + \cdots + b_{k-1}) = 1.$$
Therefore $a$ is invertible.